# Code stops working properly when scrolling too fast

Tags: jquery, scroll, show-hide

I have this code that a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885540/jquery-code-works-but-there-must-be-a-way-to-slim-it-down) from this site was so kind to help me write. What it does is hiding and showing fixed text depending on the current hashtag and position of images. You can see the code in effect [here](http://www.runeneesgaard.dk/nyt) if you scroll down the page.

Now, the problem is that if I scroll very fast down the site or use the menu to the left, sometimes the text doesn't get hidden after being shown. Like it gets stuck even though it should not display. Also, sometimes the text jumps right before it's displayed, but I don't know if that cold be related to this issue.

The jQuery code looks like this:

```
function projectInfo() {
    var distanceFromTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        distanceFromBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    var id = window.location.hash;

    var divFromTop = $(id).offset().top,
        divFromBottom = divFromTop + $(id).height() + 150;

    if (distanceFromTop >= divFromTop && !(distanceFromBottom > divFromBottom)) {
        $(id.replace("#", ".") + "-info").fadeIn(150);
    } else {
        $(id.replace("#", ".") + "-info").fadeOut(150);
    }   
}
```

I've tried a couple of things (that didn't really work), but I guess that a solution could be to only allow 1 "*#hashtag name* + -info" class (e.g. .festival-rebranding-info) to be displayed at a time. I'm not sure how I would go about doing that, though.

Can anyone give me any pointers to that or suggest a solution which might work better?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use functions like `.fadeIn()/.fadeOut()` with multiple elements that are going to be hidden/displayed on the same spot, you should take care to cancel those operations when other elements there need to be shown. You do that with the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method. If you need to have it fully show/hide the div at that point, use the syntax `.stop('fx', true);`. Try this, should be faster as well:

```
function projectInfo() {
    var distanceFromTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        distanceFromBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    var id = window.location.hash;
    var idElement = $(id); // select the element once.
    var idWithClass = id.replace("#", ".") + "-info"; // do this once per call where possible
    $(idWithClass).stop(); // stops previous fadeIn()/fadeOut() calls.

    var divFromTop = idElement.offset().top,
        divFromBottom = divFromTop + idElement.height() + 150;

    if (distanceFromTop >= divFromTop && !(distanceFromBottom > divFromBottom)) {
        $(idWithClass).fadeIn(150);
    } else {
        $(idWithClass).fadeOut(150);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, Derek! I just tested your code (I've actually tried something a bit similar to this once) and unfortunately, for some reason more often than not, the text will only fade a certain percentage in (sometimes it's such a small amount that you can't even see it). I've tried to use show() and hide() instead of fadeIn() and fadeOut() just to see if it worked with no duration involved, but it's still acting the same way. Any ideas as to why? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Is this happening on any particular version of a specific browser, or in all cases?

Comment: The whole site is not displaying quite right in Firefox at the moment, but the issue is the same here. Chrome and Safari as well. I've only had the opportunity to test it on a Mac, though.